# Import image in resources

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'd like to add an image to the resources during runtime.
The idea is this... The user will open files using dialog box and select multiple files then the selected files will be stored to the resources.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot modify the resources embedded in the executable or DLLs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the compiler with the CSharpCodeProvider class.  Write a program first that does this with some sample resources.  Pay attention to the arguments passed to the compiler, they are visible in the Output window when you build the program.  Use CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(), passing CompilerParameters with those same options.

You can use [ResourceWriter](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter%28vs.80%29.aspx) Class in your addin or macro, which writes resources in the system-default format to an output file or an output stream. Check out the [ResourceWriter.AddResource](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter.addresource%28VS.80%29.aspx) Method.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ce28296f-e391-4df6-86fc-c289302c8482/

Comment: thanks jason, and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/eeb7864b-c7c3-45fb-88c6-1d41985a0b34/

Comment: how should i use this?

**public void AddResource (string name,byte[] value)**

.sorry for this because this is the first time i use c#

Comment: here is a sample code and solution: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/DotNet_Resx_Translator.aspx